# RStata - 'RStata.log': No such file or directory

Tags: r, stata

What can I do to avoid the error below when running this code?

```
library(RStata) 
options("RStata.StataPath" = "C:/Program Files (x86)/Stata14/Stata-64.exe") options("RStata.StataVersion" = 14)
stata_src <- '   
set more off   
sysuse auto   
reg mpg weight'
stata(stata_src)
```

Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(con, "r") :
cannot open file 'RStata.log': No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error as you when I tried to open Stata in R. Probably, you can find a solution in the following way. If you are a windows user you could use `chooseStataBin()`. I used this commmand directly in Rstudio and I chose the path where my executable Stata is. The code was the following in my case:

```
stata_path = "\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Stata15\\StataMP-64\""
options("RStata.StataPath" = stata_path)
options("RStata.StataVersion" = 15)
```

Note that you have to exclude de suffix .exe.
I hope this could help to you